# Is it possible to create an if-then statement for decimal points?

Tags: java

I have a fraction calculator GUI and I need a conditional where it only accepts whole numbers and outputs an error message if a user enters a decimal point when entering a number.

[image]

Here is my GUI.

Here is my code for the GUI:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == this.computeButton){
        try {
            Fraction f1 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Num1.getText()), Integer.parseInt(Den1.getText()));
            Fraction mixed1 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Mixed1.getText()),1);
            Fraction f2 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Num2.getText()), Integer.parseInt(Den2.getText()));
            Fraction mixed2 = new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(Mixed2.getText()),1);
            Fraction ff1= f1.mul(mixed1);
            Fraction ff2 = f2.mul(mixed2);
            if (!Mixed1.getText().isEmpty())
                ff1.setWholeNumber(Integer.parseInt(Mixed1.getText()));
            if (!Mixed2.getText().isEmpty()){
                ff2.setWholeNumber(Integer.parseInt(Mixed2.getText()));
            }
            Fraction res;
            switch (comboBox1.getSelectedIndex()){
                case 0: //addition
                    res = ff1.add(ff2);

                    break;
                case 1://subtraction
                    res = ff1.sub(ff2);
                    break;
                case 2://multiplication
                    res = ff1.mul(ff2);
                    break;
                case 3://division
                    res = ff1.div(ff2);
                    break;

                default: res = new Fraction(1,1);
            }
            Label.setText(res.getResult());
            Decimal.setText(Double.toString(res.toDecimal()));
        }catch (Exception ex){
         ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to just create a method for this sort of problem?

Comment: If you try to parse a number with a decimal using Integer.parseInt(), it will throw a NumberFormatException exception.  So why not just attempt to parse an integer, catch that exception, and notify the user that they've made a bad input if that occurs?  You could wrap such a call in a method to create a "boolean isValidInteger(String str)" function.  You could also look specifically for a decimal, but using Integer.parseInt() will catch all such problems with the input.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to write a function that verifies that a String is a valid integer value:

```
boolean isValidInteger(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could also incorporate the error handling into your own parsing of the input so that you don't need to call Integer.parseInt() twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parseInt to get required result. 
JOptionPane can display what’s wrong with input

```
JTextField txtField = new JTextField();
int displayValue;
String displayTextField = txtField.getText();
if(!"".equals(displayTextField ))
{
  try
  {
   displayValue = Integer.parseInt(displayTextField);
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
   javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Wrong number, please enter Integer number", "Error", javax.swing.JOptionPane.PLAIN_MASSAGE);
   return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to throw an error if the user enters a decimal point?  A better UI which will lead to a better user experience will simply prevent the user from entering anything but digits, and possibly the sign symbol.

You can achieve that by setting a [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) via [TextField.setTextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setTextFormatter-javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter-) which will ensure that the value is a valid integer.

If you still want to check whether a value has a decimal point or not you can do so easily either by trying to parse it with Integer.parseInt() (or Long.parseLong()), or by iterating over the characters and ensuring that all of the characters are a digit, allowing the first character to be a sign symbol.